# Where are the meta post about the edit trick?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

May I ask where are all the meta posts about the edit tricks that reveals deleted post to users less than 10k?

I searched on SO and even on Google, and I cannot find any trace of them. Have they been recently deleted? I am quite sure there are a bunch of such duplicate questions, since I have seen them bumped up to the active tab when one of the moderators close them as duplicate.

Comment: also <10k only see question not answer by that trick

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer: Do you have a deleted answer? Just want to test at 2k rep.

Comment: here you go http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157475/176320 :)

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer: It is possible at 2k rep for deleted answer.

Comment: afaik its not ... we can only see deleted question  and  if we  try with answer's url  it will show question

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer: Content of your post: ``you can do this by `ctrl+k` or 4 space before line or 

 
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5xAtn.png``

Comment: you are right .. how you saw that could i have like you tried ?

Comment: `/posts/157475/edit`

Comment: thankyou i  used wrong id of answer ...

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer: Just tested. If you don't log in, you can access any deleted post (question or answer).